# Clearcase mvfs error while running the build in windows dynamic view

Tags: build, clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I have the following error while running the build in the dynamic view. It looks like an mvfs caching problem.
The build succeeded after I ran it few times but what might be the problem behind it?

```
pid/tid 900/938} cleartext lookup view= vob= dbid=0x80000173 - error 6
[2013/12/14 02:56:10.233] mvfs: Error: {858 pid/tid 900/938} cleartext pname= \Device\Mup\.......\.s\00030\8000017352aab277sc100-elf2xx.exe
[2013/12/14 02:56:18.603] mvfs: Error: {859 pid/tid 900/938} cleartext lookup view= vob= dbid=0x80000173 - error 6
[2013/12/14 02:56:18.603] mvfs: Error: {860 pid/tid 900/938} cleartext pname= \Device\Mup\.....\.s\00030\8000017352aab277sc100-elf2xx.exe
[2013/12/14 02:56:24.951] mvfs: Error: {861 pid/tid 900/938} mvfs_nt2vfs_opensendirp:  failed OPEN irp fop 0xFFFFFA800EF21700 status 0xc000006d [2013/12/14 02:56:24.951] mvfs: Error: {862 pid/tid 900/938} DriverName: \FileSystem\FltMgr 
[2013/12/14 02:56:24.951] mvfs: Error: {863 pid/tid 900/938} FileName: ....\.s\00030\8000011952aab271objcopy.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering the objects which are troublesome in the [private storage area](https://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/c_viewadm_dynamic.htm) (`.s`) of the view storage are `.exe`, it is possible it is linked to some kind of process keeping an handle on said exe, and preventing ClearCase to properly access them.

It is best to use two dynamic views: one for accessing data, and one for building data, in order to use one for read/access and execution, and the other for write access and compilation.

This old thread mentions restarting the [albd_server](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000013874382) service can help.
That is also akin to stopping / restarting the view (`cleartool endview -server`).

Comment: I am not sure if increasing the view cache limit by: ct setcache -view -cachesize 1M <view-tag> will help. what is your input on this, view has currently 512kb cache limit? Also, running the build in a view I imported from unix, does the credential has to be same or Can I run the build with different credential?

Comment: @user2370590 my input is not to linger too much on the issue: if a second view can help to alleviate the issue, that would be enough. And don't import a view, create a local one with the right config spec, created by a user with the right CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP (the one allowed to access the vob)

Comment: Hi Von, does this CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP should be system variable or user variable?

Comment: @user2370590 always user variable, not system.